# Given a 2d array of Ints, how do I find the highest numbers and their positions?

Tags: arrays, swift

Given a 2D array `brightnessMap` which contains `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`, how do find both the highest x numbers, in order (say, x=3 to get 9, 8, 7) AND their positions (2,2 ; 2,1; 2,0)?

Comment: How would you do it given a single array? `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: don't know. if the numbers were always unique I could do something like `array.index(of: array.max())` to get the highest, but I am not guaranteeing uniqueness.

Comment: Well you can combine the indices with the elements: `zip(array.indices, array)`, and you can then find the max by the elements, while keeping the corresponding indices.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Isn't that what `enumerated()` does? :)

Comment: @Sulthan Nope, enumerated is more like `zip(0..., array)`. The resulting indices aren't indices, they're offsets. They always start at 0, and can't be used to index back into the collection, in the general case. Try it on String, or Dictionary, for example.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Oh, you are right about that. In case of array they are the same though.

Comment: @Sulthan Yep. But then you have to be careful with things like `a.dropFirst().enumerated()` vs `a.enumerated().dropFirst()`, because they're not the same.

Comment: having trouble getting the `zip` to work (does it need to be in a loop?), can u post a code snippet as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `enumerated` method and the beauty of flat map:

```
let brightnessMap = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
let count = 3
let result = brightnessMap
    .enumerated() 
    .map { x, elts in elts.enumerated().map { y, value in  (pos: (x,y), value: value) } }
    .flatMap { $0 }
    .sorted { $0.value > $1.value }
    .prefix(count)
```

The `result` will contain this array of tuples:

```
[(pos: (2, 2), value: 9), (pos: (2, 1), value: 8), (pos: (2, 0), value: 7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most elegant solution but it does the job

```
func maxFromArrays(_ maxCount: Int ) -> [Int: [(Int,Int)]] {
    let max3 = array.flatMap {$0}.sorted().suffix(3)
    var positions: [Int: [(Int,Int)]] = [:]

    for (index, value) in array.enumerated() {
        for (index2, value2) in value.enumerated() {
            if max3.contains(value2) {
                positions[value2, default: []].append((index, index2))
            }
        }
    }
    return positions
}
```

Borrowing `makeList` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28140271/9223839) we can test it with some larger arrays

```
func makeList(_ n: Int) -> [Int] {
    return (0..<n).map { _ in .random(in: 1...20) }
}

let array = [makeList(10), makeList(10), makeList(10)] 
print(array)
print(maxFromArrays(3))
```

> [[11, 3, 15, 7, 1, 7, 5, 17, 13, 8], [13, 9, 7, 15, 4, 17, 7, 17, 17, 2], [9, 18, 13, 15, 12, 2, 11, 20, 4, 16]]
>   [18: [(2, 1)], 17: [(0, 7), (1, 5), (1, 7), (1, 8)], 20: [(2, 7)]]